# Grails: 404 and lazy initialization

Tags: grails

If you visit a page that does not exist, and a 404 is "thrown" and Grails goes to try to render my custom 404 error page, I get lazy initialization errors from some taglibs I have that are executed in the error layout.

The taglib does in fact try to access a domain object inside of another domain object that is a has-many relationship.  It is able to get the initial object, but when accessing the relationship, it throws this lazy initialization error.

However, this does not happen when any other page is accessed properly. Even if I try to access my custom error page directly.  Only when a 404 error is thrown.

Is there something different about the hibernate session during this time that causes the lazy initialization error?

Is it possible that accessing something that is lazily initialized in a taglib is not a good idea in Grails?

Comment: I have the same problem right now. But it's the tag sec:ifNotLogIn in Spring Security plugin. It doesn't work like expected, though not throw an exception.

Comment: I've been looking all over and can't find a solution to this.  I've found some Grails bugs that are still unresolved that sound like they're related, but I'm not completely sure.

Comment: How's the taglib reading the domain object? Is it queried via GORM using an existing ID? Or do you read it from the session?

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this before, and my usual solution would be to move the querying to the controller.  I believe this is due to the fact that the controller and GSP sessions are not one and the same - hence, it's a good idea to do most database reads within a controller.

In this case, there is no controller.

As far as hacks to get around this problem ...

I a wondering if you can't [start a session/end a session](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/withSession.html) within your GSP and/or taglib to force the behavior for now.  Another idea is to force a read of the relationship at the same time you access the original (parent) object - this will initialize the lazy relationship.

Comment: It works when one wraps the database access with a `withSession {}` call.